# How to select dates in a week from a week number in mySql

Tags: mysql

How can i select the rows with all dates in a given week number?

I have rows with dates like: 2019-01-05, 2019-01-08 etc
Now i would like to select all these dates thats in week 1, week 2 or week 5.

`SELECT * FROM mytable`
`WHERE myDateColumn = WEEK(5)`

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`WHERE week(myDateColumn) in (1,2,5)`

Comment: Code-only answers are low value on Stackoverflow because they do very little to educate/empower thousands of future researchers.

Answer (score 0):

I found no other solution than use mySQL BETWEEN.

First find start and end date for the week number:

```
$dto = new DateTime();
$week_start = $dto->setISODate($chosenYear, $chosenWeek)->format('Y-m-d');
$week_end = $dto->modify('+6 days')->format('Y-m-d');
```

Then use BETWEEN

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE date BETWEEN '$week_start' AND '$week_end'
```